# Looping Through SQL Results in PHP - Not getting Entire Array

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I'm probably missing something easy, but I seem to be blocked here...  I have a MySQL database with two tables and each table has several rows.  So the goal is to query the database and display the results in a table, so I start like so:

`$query = "SELECT name, email, phone FROM users";`

Then I have this PHP code:

`$result = mysql_query($query);`

Then, I use this to get array:

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

At this point, I thought I could simply loop through the `$row` array and display results in a table.  I already have a function to do the looping and displaying of the table, but unfortunately the array seems to be incomplete before it even gets to the function.

To troubleshoot this I use this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
    echo $row[$i] . " ";
}
```

At this point, I only get the first row in the database, and there are 3 others that aren't displaying.  Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: foreach($row as $r){echo $r['name']." ".$r['email'];} for example

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the following because if you call `mysql_fetch_array` outside of the loop, you're only returning an array of all the elements in the first row. By setting row to a new row returned by `mysql_fetch_array` each time the loop goes through, you will iterate through each row instead of whats actually inside the row.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   // This will loop through each row, now use your loop here

}
```

But the good way is to iterate through each row,  as you have only three columns

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo $row['name']." ";
   echo $row['email']." ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this gets my array.  Now I just need to figure out why my loop/display function isn't working as it should.

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_array are depracated

Answer (score 4):

One common way to loop through results is something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
    // do stuff with $row
}
```

Check out the examples and comments on PHP.net.  You can find everything you need to know there.