# While or foreach loop insde an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am fetching data from server and show in an array. Like this:

```
include 'config.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM author";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);
```

```
$response = array(
array('id' => $row['id'],  'name' => $row['name'], 'email' => $row['email'], 'picture_path' => $row['picture_path']),
);
```

it show me a single result but I want all the result through loop, help me fetch all data from database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping Through SQL Results in PHP - Not getting Entire Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243383/looping-through-sql-results-in-php-not-getting-entire-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost all correct, you want to put the `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);` with a loop:

```
include 'config.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM author";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response = array(
        array('id' => $row['id'],  'name' => $row['name'], 'email' => $row['email'], 'picture_path' => $row['picture_path']),
    );
}
```

But if you want to just echo the results out skip the array and just use:

```
echo "id: " . $row['id'] . " name: " . $row['name']. " email " . $row['email']. "picture_path" . $row['picture_path'];
```

Comment: because I am new so I have to wait for 5 mins :( wait for a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) 
{
  print_r($row);
}
```

it should be helpfull.

Comment: Where should I place this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a foreach to iterate through the $row array.

```
$response = array();

foreach ($row as $data)
{
    $response[] = array(
        'id' => $data['id'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'picture_path' => $data['picture_path'])
    );
}
```

Comment: See the above answer. You will know whats wrong with your code :/

Comment: Your question said "while OR foreach loop". This is another way of doing it. You would put this code after the $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. Please mark this as a valid answer if you are happy that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Loop your array using foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($row as  $res){
 echo $res['id'];
 echo $res['name'];
 // continue like this....

}
```

It will echo your array from database.