# PHP: For loop that repeats the first item instead of looping through all items?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a MySQL query that requests a list of items.

I fetch for them and want to display every item with a for loop, **but it shows me just the first item repeated, instead of every item.**

Why?

```
<?php 

$conectar = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
$query = "  SELECT cursoID, nombreCurso, estadoCurso
            FROM cursos 
            WHERE estadoCurso='abierto'";
$buscarCurso = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
$curso=mysqli_fetch_assoc($buscarCurso);
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($buscarCurso); //There are 3 rows of results

echo $totalRows;

for ($i=0; $i < $totalRows; $i++) { 
    echo '<br>';
    echo $curso['nombreCurso'];
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

The intended result is:

Curso 1

Curso 2

Curso 3

And instead I get

Curso 1

Curso 1

Curso 1

Comment: Add print_r($curso); before your `for` loop and see what is on the $curso['nombreCurso'] field first?

Comment: Why don't you do it as described in the PHP documentation? As you do it, it is indeed wrong. You don't move forward in your result set.

Comment: You're fetching an associated array, which returns one row. Instead of `for` you should say `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($buscarCurso)) {...echo stuff...}` You do not need to get a row count

Comment: seems not much research was done before asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243383/looping-through-sql-results-in-php-not-getting-entire-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loop should be fetching from the result set on every iteration. The standard way  (as in many examples given in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1908)) is that you do this in the `while` condition:

```
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($buscarCurso); //There are 3 rows of results
echo $totalRows;
while ($curso=mysqli_fetch_assoc($buscarCurso)) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $curso['nombreCurso'];
    echo '<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But it seems that loop 2 times, I mean one time less than it takes to finish.

Comment: You have to remove the original line where you call `mysqli_feth_assoc` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for the query result. In this case, you'll get just one result and loop through that result 3 times.

```
<?php
while($curso = mysqli_fetch_assoc($buscarCurso)) {

    // Do some stuff
    echo '<br />' . $curso['nombreCurso'] . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First use prepared statement for block SQL injection than check this code

```
<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);


$select_cursos = $conn->prepare(" SELECT 
    cursoID, nombreCurso, estadoCurso
    FROM cursos 
    WHERE estadoCurso = ? ORDER BY nombreCurso ASC 
");

$select_cursos->bind_param('s', $nombreCurso);

$nombreCurso = 'abierto'; // This you can get from a $_POST too

if (!$select_cursos->execute()) { // ERROR

    echo('Error');

} else { // OK
    $select_cursos_result = $select_cursos->get_result();
    $select_cursos_count = select_cursos_result->num_rows;

    echo('Found: '.$select_cursos_count);

    if ($select_cursos_count > 0) {
        while ($data = $select_cursos_result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo ($data['nombreCurso'].'<br>');
        }
    } else {
        echo ('No data!!');
    }
}

?>
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Complete answer the people doesn't like!! :D